# Link on Gmail API Support is incorrect

Tags: gmail-api

Wasn't sure where else to put this but the Gmail API support page said it monitors stackoverflow. I wanted to let the engineers know the link on https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support that should point to the Gmail-api stackoverflow tag points to google drive tag.

> We support the Gmail REST API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers
>   monitor and answer questions with the **gmail-api** tag.

The hyperlink on gmail-api points to google drive sdk:

[I had a screenshot but don't have the reputation to post images yet.] Here is a link: http://screencast.com/t/Xaz0nRRO1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed now.  Updated at:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support

Answer (score 0):

There is some mistake in the documentation. You should check the link in the below of page(just down to Ask a question)that is [Gmail API on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api) or you can file issue on [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/).

[image]